# Scrapy works in shell but not when I call my spider

Tags: xpath, web-crawler, scrapy

I have been working on this for the past few hours, but cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. When I run my xpath states using the selector in the scrapy shell, the statement works as expected. When I try to use the same statement in my spider, however, I get back an empty set. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from TFFRS.items import Result

class AthleteSpider(Spider):
        name = "athspider"
        allowed_domains = ["www.tffrs.org"]
        start_urls = ["http://www.tffrs.org/athletes/3237431/",]

        def parse(self, response):
            sel = Selector(response)
            results = sel.xpath("//table[@id='results_data']/tr")
            items = []
            for r in results:
                item = Result()
                item['event'] = r.xpath("td[@class='event']").extract()
                items.append(item)
            return items
```

Comment: Without any HTML, it's hard to tell. The URL you indicate contains almost only javascript, and no tag with the id you're looking for. How did you feed your scrapy shell with the HTML?

Comment: are you sure about this start_url? it says that domain is for sale

Comment: I just checked it and yeah, it's just ads. There's no "results_data" there at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When viewed by the spider your url contains no content. To debug this kind of problems you should use [scrapy.shell.inspect_response](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html#invoking-the-shell-from-spiders-to-inspect-responses) in parse method, use it like so:

```py
from scrapy.shell import inspect_response

class AthleteSpider(Spider):

    # all your code    
    def parse(self, response):
        inspect_response(response, self)
```

then when you do

```
scrapy crawl <your spider>
```

you will get a shell from within your spider. There you should do:

```
In [1]: view(response)
```

This will display this particular response as it looks for this particular spider.

Answer (score 0):

Try using HtmlXPathSelector for extracting xpaths.
Remove `http` from the `start_urls` section. Also the table id is something you are not entering correctly in your xpath. Try using inspect element to get a proper xpath for the data you want to scrape.

also consider changing function name, from docs:

> Warning
>
> When writing crawl spider rules, avoid using parse as callback, since
>   the CrawlSpider uses the parse method itself to implement its logic.
>   So if you override the parse method, the crawl spider will no longer
>   work

Comment: how is this related to his problem? as far as I can see he isnt using CrawlSpider

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy spiders must implement specific methods; examples are: `parse` and `start_requests` but there are others in [docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html)
So if you don't implement these methods for that, you will have problem. In my case the problem was i had a typo and my function name was *start_request* instead of *start_requests*!
so make sure your skeleton is something like this:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "name"
    allowed_domains = ["https://example.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://example.com/']

    def start_requests(self):
        #start_request method

    def parse(self, response):
        #parse method
```